# To display the total number of records minus one in a file in UNIX script passes as parameter

Tags: shell-script, ksh

The input is provided in the following format:

```
ksh -x count.sh filename `cat filepath/filename | wc -l
```

Here the problem is that I need to pass the second parameter cat to another variable and to do `expr -1`.

My requirement is that I need to calculate the count in the command itself, and to pass it to the script.

Total number of records should be less than 1 for the actual count. I also need to remove the header record.

Comment: To remove a header line, you could replace `cat` with `tail -n +2`

Comment: Don't understand "remove the header record". Is that just why the count has to be -1? Or do you wish to *edit* the file too, either in situ, or by copying to stdout, or a different filename? Or is the `filename` arg to count.sh different to the one in `/filepath`, as it seems to have no other purpose unless to be a place to copy the edited file?

Comment: UUOC anyway. The expression could be: `$(( $( wc -l < "filename" ) - 1))`

Comment: There is a quoting error in your code.

Answer (score 6):

The total number of records in a file, minus one, is easiest had with `awk`:

```
awk 'END { print NR - 1 }' filename
```

This prints the value of `NR` minus one, where `NR` is an internal variable that holds the number of records read so far.  This is done at the end of input, giving you the total number of records in the file, minus one.

Your command could then possibly be written as

```
ksh -x count.sh filename "$( awk 'END { print NR - 1 }' filename )"
```